# C Primer Plus Chapter 6 Exercise 4

Tags: c, runtime-error

Use nested loops to produce the following

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

Here is what I have so far. I end up getting a nasty runtime error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int row;
    char let;
    char ch = 'A';

    for (row = 1; row <= 6; row++) {

        for (let = ch; let < (let + row); let++) {

            printf("%c", let);

        }

        ch = let;
        printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not really sure what to do at this point. Is the error a result of
the letter not updating?

Comment: @segarci ,OP mentioned that he gets a Runtime error

Comment: @CoolGuy - Run time errors have many flavours

Comment: "Not really sure what to do at this point " - Debugging would be a good place to start. This one you don't even need a formal debugger. A pencil, sheet of paper, and three columns would quickly show where the wheels fall off.

Comment: @EdHeal , You mean that anything can happen once you get a Runtime error?

Comment: @CoolGuy - I did not say that. Run time error can be lack of memory, stack overflow, floating point overflow, memory leaks, ....

Answer (score 2):

your loop never breaks as condition `let < (let + row);`  is always true! e.g. hint: how can `1 < (1 + i)` ??

Comment: That depends whether his compiler provides a signed or unsigned `char` type.  The C standard doesn't specify.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for (let = ch; let < (let + row); let++)
```

to

```
for (let = ch; let < (ch + row); let++)
```

or else,you get an infinite loop as `let < (let + row)` will never be false. This may vary between compilers. The C standard doesn't specify whether `let` is an `unsigned char` or a `signed char`. So its up to the compiler to decide it.

If `let` was an `unsigned char`,then the loop will loop and eventually,`(let+row)` will wrap around(due to overflow) to the value 0 and then,the loop ends.
If `let` was a `signed char`,then eventually,`(let+row)` will overflow and can hold any value. This leads to Undefined Behavior and one cannot guarantee that the loop will end or not.

Comment: That depends whether his compiler provides a signed or unsigned `char` type.  The C standard doesn't specify.

Comment: @BenVoigt , So if `let` was an `unsigned char`,then the loop will end soon and if `let` was `signed`,then it would be UB?

Answer (score 1):

Is this bit

```
let < (let + row)
```

going to always be true?

Comment: That depends whether his compiler provides a signed or unsigned `char` type.  The C standard doesn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
for (let = 0; let <  row; let++) {
    printf("%c", ch + let);
}
ch += let;
```

Comment: You should elaborate on the OP problem.